# Function to sequentially apply modifications to a string

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes a substring and a string and finds matching occurrences of the substring in the string and changes matching characters to uppercase. For example:

```
> upperCase "aaa" "---aaa---"
"---AAA---"
```

I'd like to use this function, but apply the upperCase operation using several substrings. For example:

```
> upperCases ["aaa", "bbb", "c"] "d---aaa---c--bbb"
"d---AAA---C--BBB"
```

What I'm struggling to understand is how I can do this. Here's my best attempt:

```
upperCases [] st = st
upperCases [x] st = upperCase x st
upperCases (x:xs) st = upperCases xs st
```

When I use this `upperCases` function in the example above, I get the following incorrect output:

```
"d---aaa---C--bbb"
```

Only the last substring is being changed. What is wrong with this function and I can I write a function to perform the example operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're simply "throwing away" the `x` from the pattern `x:xs`. Obviously, you need to use that first before recursing to the other matches!

```
upperCases (x:xs) st = upperCases xs $ upperCase x st
```

However, it would be better to not write out the recursion explicitly. What you want is basically, chaining together a bunch of functions. That's a fold:

```
chain :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
chain = foldr (.) id
```

Now, at the moment you don't have functions `a->a`. Rather, you have `b->a->a`, where both `b` and `a` are in fact `String`. But you can apply the first argument partially, e.g.

```
[upperCase "aaa", upperCase "bbb", upperCase "c"] :: [String -> String]
```

More concisely, this list could be defined by `map upperCase ["aaa", "bbb", "c"]`.

So all in all, you need

```
upperCases = foldr (.) id . map upperCase
```

Actually, you can even include the `upperCase` in the fold:

```
upperCases = foldr ((.) . upperCase) id
```

Comment: Is there a  Haskell linter tool that would warn on an unused variable like that `x`?

Comment: @misterbee GHC has a [lot of warning options](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html). -fwarn-unused-binds option does just that, and -Wall enables a lot of extra warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add a small comment to leftaroundabout's answer: A function that maps from a structure to itself is in mathematics called an [endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism). In Haskell it's straightforward to represent the set of all functions (endomorphisms) on type `a` as `a -> a`, and we have a data type for that named [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aEndo).

Since endomorphisms are composable using `.` and since for any `f` we have `f . id` equals to `id . f` equals to `f`, they naturally form a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). This monoid is sometimes called [the transformation monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_monoid). In Haskell this is witnessed by the `Monoid` instance of `Endo`.

Now the composition of such functions is just combining elements in this monoid. So we can define `upperCases` as

```
import Data.Monoid

upperCases :: [String] -> String -> String
upperCases = appEndo . mconcat . map (Endo . upperCase)
```

We first map string patterns into their respective endomorphisms, concatenate them in their monoid and then just extract the resulting function.

Working with `Endo` (or other) monoids often provides a nice alternative to folding.